# ASP.NET MVC Controllers properly initialized when testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing, controller, integration-testing

How do I get an ASP.NET MVC controller properly initialized for an integration test?

My current problem is that when I try to access the User member of a controller I get:

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

What I want is what Ruby on Rails provides out of the box with the Functional Tests.

Comment: Thank you for the comments on running a whole web server. I'll keep that as a last resource since it complicates everything a lot (it won't use my test database, I'll have to deal with HTTP instead of just creating a controller and calling methods, I'll have to fix a port that is good for everybody, etc). There should be a better way with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2):

To fire up Cassini from a unit test

```
 [TestMethod()]

 [HostType("ASP.NET")]

 [UrlToTest("http://localhost:25153/WebSite1")]
```

[More information on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182526%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

How about having a gander at this from Steve Sanderson - [MVCIntegrationTestFramework](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/)

Looks pretty freakin cool!

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: Sounds very close to what I want. Am I right in assuming that the demo project is the only downloadable thing it's offered? The framework is not offered anywhere else than in the demo, or so it seems.

Comment: One problem that I see though is that it'll use whatever database is configured in web.config, that mean it'll normally use the dev database, instead of the test database I generate on the fly for the tests.

Comment: You could couple it with something like this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx ...?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fire up an instance of the webserver, whether it be IIS or the built-in Visual Studio one. The unit testing in Visual Studio doesn't initiate a instance of the site by default.

Comment: How do I fire up IIS or Casini from a test?

Answer (score 0):

You have few choices:

1. Mock HttpContextBase - there're plenty of articles on the subject
2. Use injection - pass IUserContext to controller, and mock it in tests (in real app it will be something HttpUserContext)
3. Use model binder: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IPrincipalUserModelBinderInASPNETMVCForEasierTesting.aspx

And I'm sure there's more, for example, make your BaseController and fake GetUser() there as needed.

Comment: But I don't want to mock any of those, because I want to make sure my application works fine with the real context, the real session, etc.

Comment: Sorry, missed that word. Then your choice is one of the options suggested here. MVCIntegrationTestFramework looks promising. This post seems to explain AppDomain technique a bit deeper: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/2008/06/24/hosting-an-entire-asp-net-mvc-request-for-testing-purposes.aspx.

Comment: Or just use WatiN/Selenium, but of course with PageObject technique to eliminate code duplication.